# If BE and CF are altitudes of the acute-angled triangle ABC, prove that AF · AB = AE · AC

Tags: euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

If BE and CF are altitudes of the acute-angled triangle ABC,
prove that AF · AB = AE · AC

[image]

Comment: Consider several circles and use power of point

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- Notice that the triangles $ABE$ and $ACF$ are similar, thus...
- or notice that $BCEF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and thus...

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{AF}{b}$$ and $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{AE}{c}$$